# Proof regarding curl of a vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vector-fields, flow, angular-velocity, vortex

I'm stuck in this problem where we need to prove that the curl of the velocity vector is twice the angular velocity of a rigid body in circular motion. How do I prove it? I am very new to the concepts of Curl, Gradient in Physics and hence was not able to do much. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/4.-triple-integrals-and-surface-integrals-in-3-space/part-c-line-integrals-and-stokes-theorem/session-90-curl-in-3d/MIT18_02SC_MNotes_v4.3.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This question falls into the "homework-and-exercises" category of Physics StackExchange, so you shouldn't necessarily expect a complete solution. What I aim to do here is provide a few guidelines.

I suggest firstly approaching this using explicit $(x,y,z)$ components, rather than grapple with vector formulae. Choose the angular velocity $\mathbf{\omega}$ to lie in the $z$-direction: $\boldsymbol{\omega}=(0,0,\omega)$. Take the rigid body to lie in the $xy$ plane (although this is not essential).

For any point in the body $(x,y,0)$, you should be able to write down the velocity vector components $(v_x,v_y,0)$ as functions of $x$ and $y$, due to the rigid-body rotation. The formula will also involve the components of $\boldsymbol{\omega}$, which are constants (in this case, $\omega_z=\omega$ is the only one).

Hopefully it is obvious that the $z$-component of velocity is zero,
and it should also be clear that $v_x$ and $v_y$ only depend on $x$ and $y$ anyway, so making the rigid body lie in the $xy$ plane was not essential.

Next, check the formula defining the curl, in terms of derivatives of the components of velocity with respect to the positional components. Write it down. Unless something is seriously amiss, your final formula will be a vector pointing in the $z$ direction, which should match your expected answer.

It is then possible to tackle this problem in full vector form; possibly that is what you are expected to do. First step is to write the velocity $\mathbf{v}$ as a function of $\boldsymbol{\omega}$ and position $\mathbf{r}$. Then you need an expression for the curl of a vector product of two vectors (only one of which actually depends on position); this means being (or becoming) familiar with the general formula for $\mathbf{a}\times(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c})$ and thinking about evaluating this when $\mathbf{a}$ is replaced by the gradient $\mathbf{\nabla}$.
It is actually more straightforward than it might seem at first: you can always think about it in terms of the components.